# Circular reference detected for service "security.context"

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, twig

I tried to inject the templating service and this is what I get.

```
<service id="myproject_notification.service.mail" class="%myproject_notification.service.mail.class%">
    <argument type="service" id="mailer" />
    <argument type="service" id="templating" />
</service>
```

[image: 2014-06-10 12-37-10]

If I comment, or remove, the templating service from the dependency, everything is working well. I saw old issues about that, but it seems I'm the only one at the moment experiencing this. Am I doing something wrong?

**Composer.json**

```
"symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
"twig/extensions": "~1.0",
"symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
"symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
"sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
"sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
"incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
```

**Composer.lock**

```
"name": "symfony/symfony",
"version": "v2.5.0",
...
"name": "twig/twig",
"version": "v1.15.1",
```

Comment: What does your `%myproject_notification.service.mail.class%` look like? Namely what class does it extend? Maybe you already have templating available in that class.

Comment: It is a simple class I wrote myself, without any extends, just the constructor(SwiftMailer, TemplatingEngine) and a function sendMailToUser(User). Ho and my cache has been cleared with php app/console and rm -rf, so that is not the problem :(

Comment: You may consider rethinking your services design. Avoiding circular dependencies remains the best practice. If you really need it, what about [lazy services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/lazy_services.html) ?

Comment: As said [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11087#issuecomment-45617054), I don't think my design is wrong. Or I will have to copy/paste in different files the same business logic. But the lazy service seems a good alternative for my notification service. What are the cons of this?

Comment: @Litz I didn't mean it was wrong, I just meant you could give it a rethinking. As stated by stof, using evented mechanism seems to be a good alternative. Lazy services tend to be slower on light object with since it must reflect the class and each properties to create a new proxy (dev mode), and adds a function call for each method. The purpose of lazy services is to lighten objects with heavy instanciation/work (and keep its print) in order to load them only when needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This solution is a quick way to fix the problem. This can be avoided, please read comments.**

For this particular case it may be best to inject the `ServiceContainer` into your service. As it seems that you are experiencing an edge case, where the `security.context` is already injected into some `templating` services (e.g. helpers), which then in your example is injected back (indirectly) to the `security.context`.

Try this:

```
<service id="myproject_notification.service.mail" class="%myproject_notification.service.mail.class%">
    <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
</service>
```

And in your class's constructor, use it as follows:

```
class YourMailerClass
{
    protected $container; 

   public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container )
   {
     $this->container = $container; 
    } 

    public function sendMail()
    {
       $mailer = $this->container->get('mailer');
       $templating = $this->container->get('templating');
    }

}
```

See this conversation between the Symfony Core developers about the same problem: 
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2347

For most cases injecting the service container is ***not advised*** for [several reasons](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html#avoiding-your-code-becoming-dependent-on-the-container).

Comment: I tried this. I was hoping this quick dirty solution to work, but no :/. I get the same error on the ->get('templating'); Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok, my bad. I was doing the ->get() in the Constructor (which means doing the same thing as injecting in parameters). This solution works. :). I will validate it in one day max!

Comment: Actually, injecting the service container is not advised because it's a terrible practice. It hides the real dependencies of your object and breaks the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) leading to hard/incorrect unit testing

Comment: Thanks @Touki, I also commented in my answer. But please see and observe the number of service injections in the original question which is obviously an edge case. Then read the blog entry I also added, where Fabien himself advises to inject the ServiceContainer to avoid circular dependencies in such cases (especially templating-related cases): https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2347#issuecomment-2838590

Comment: You say *"not advised for **performance** and **efficiency reasons**"* which was not complete, I was just giving additionnal informations. Moreover Fabien doesn't **advise** to use it. When he says *"The solution depends on the service for which there is a circular reference problem"* I think he means *"You should rethink your service declaration"*. He only gives a quick-and-dirty solution to avoid this exception.

Comment: I think we could go on explaining the bad practices behind injecting the `ServiceContainer` (but this was not part of the question.) I assure you I am ***not*** in favor of it either. But having circular dependency problems around `security.context` and `templating` may not be addressed as easy as simply rethinking. As Fabien stated *'templating service relies on a lot of other services.'* For this particular case this should suffice and in my opinion will not cause severe problems.

Comment: I both thank you for the advices and the constructive debate. For the future readers, I would like to link the symfony related issue and the stof solution ([link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11087#issuecomment-45618643)). He submits the idea of using symfony2 events.

Comment: did not work anymore on symfony 2.5, seems like get container getting smarter :(

Comment: **Its bad practice** injecting the container into your service. So you make your service dependent to the container. Good luck when you change the framework. You understand my point?

Answer (score 13):

You should always try to avoid injecting container directly to your services.

I think the best possible solution to the «circular reference» problem as well as to possible performance issues, would be to use «[Lazy Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/lazy_services.html)» feature available starting from Symfony 2.3.

Just mark you dependency as `lazy` in your service container configuration and install ProxyManager Bridge (look for details in Lazy Services documentation above).

I hope that helps, cheers.

Comment: As far as I know, lazy service won't prevent circular reference exception since circular dependency still exists.

Comment: Actually, it will prevent it, because dependant services will be initialized in two different phases.

Comment: But circular reference exception isn't thrown when initializing services. It is thrown on cache warmup when dependency graph is calculated? At least that seemed to be the case last time I had issues with it.

Comment: I'm not sure about the details, but it helped me in the past to overcome this specific problem. Maybe something has changed since then regarding DIC implementation.

Comment: @SlavaFominII thanks, this worked for a `Twig_Extension` requiring the `templating` service!

@IgorPantović No problems with `bin/console cache:clear`

Answer (score 0):

```
composer require symfony/proxy-manager-bridge
```

That's what your need to solve this ....

Check the [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/lazy_services.html) for more info....

And do not forget to set the services with :

```
lazy : true
```